# How to get started with Android Studio C++ development

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk

I heard at Google I/O 15 that Android Studio has now C++ support, the official [documentation for the NDK](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html) only has instructions for Eclipse.

How does one get started with Android C++ development using Android Studio?

Comment: Have you considered using [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is detailed instructions on the [Android NDK Preview](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview) site.

### The gist of it

- [Download](https://developer.android.com/studio) Android Studio 1.3+
- Install the NDK bundle from *Tools > Android > SDK Manager*
  [image: NDK in android sdk manager]
- Import the hello-jn sample using *File > Import Sample* (Note: This sample is using the new `gradle-experimental` plugin)
  [image: import sample diaglog]
- Click *Run > Edit Configurations...* and andd a new *Android Native* configuration
  [image: native run configuration]
  <sub>(source: [android.com](http://tools.android.com/_/rsrc/1436485240263/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview/ndk-native.png))</sub>
- Run and debug your application as usual

### A few things to try from there:

- Generate JNI bindings for Native Java function.
  [image: generate jni binding]
- Put breakpoint in native code (with the current limitation that breakpoint on init/onCreate get skipped, should be already fixed in [Android Studio 1.4 Preview](https://web.archive.org/web/20180906031806/http://tools.android.com:80/download/studio/canary))
- Give [feedback](http://tools.android.com/feedback) to the team
- Try and contribute to the [new sample on GitHub](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples)
- Explore the [new documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) and [API reference](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/index.html).